# Can I get the url of the page that I downloaded with jsoup?

Tags: java, html, url, download, jsoup

Is there a way that I could get the url of the page that I just downloaded? Not the links that are contained in the html page, but the url of the actual html page itself
?

I tried doing this,

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(child, "UTF-8", "");
string url = doc.location();
System.out.println(url);
```

but then the url would return an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the page you downloaded is a `Document`, simply call `Document.location()` to get the URL it was served from. If the URL you passed to `Jsoup.connect()` was a redirect, the `Document` location will give you the URL it was eventually served from.

Comment: I tried doing that but it would return an empty value.    `org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(child, "UTF-8", "");      string url = doc.location();                                               System.out.println(url);`

Answer (score -1):

If you used `WinHTTrack` usually it saves the URL, but what you could do is look for PHP files or JavaScript files that are connected to the site's URL. For instance the downloaded site below has a few links:

```html
<html lang="en-US">

<!-- Mirrored from brigade3.com/ by HTTrack Website Copier/3.x [XR&CO'2014], Sat, 13 Dec 2014 04:02:28 GMT -->
<!-- Added by HTTrack --><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" /><!-- /Added by HTTrack -->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <title>BukkitCloud | Beta Stage</title>
                    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
    <link rel="pingback" href="xmlrpc.php" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/uploads/2013/12/favico.png">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800,700italic,700,600italic,600,400italic,300italic,300|Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400|Lato&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext' type='text/css' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Brigade &raquo; Feed" href="feed/index.html" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Brigade &raquo; Comments Feed" href="comments/feed/index.html" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='rs-settings-css'  href='assets/plugins/revslider/rs-plugin/css/settings.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='rs-captions-css'  href='assets/plugins/revslider/rs-plugin/css/captions.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='default_style-css'  href='assets/themes/passage/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='stylesheet-css'  href='assets/themes/passage/css/stylesheet.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<!--[if IE 8]>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='ie8-style-css'  href='http://brigade3.com/assets/themes/passage/css/ie8.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='ie9-style-css'  href='http://brigade3.com/assets/themes/passage/css/ie9.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<![endif]-->
<link rel='stylesheet' id='style_dynamic-css'  href='assets/themes/passage/css/style_dynamic.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='responsive-css'  href='assets/themes/passage/css/responsive.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='style_dynamic_responsive-css'  href='assets/themes/passage/css/style_dynamic_responsive.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='custom_css-css'  href='assets/themes/passage/css/custom_css.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://brigade3.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://brigade3.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/plugins/revslider/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js'></script>
<link rel='prev' title='FEATURES' href='features/index.html' />
<link rel='next' title='CONTACT' href='contact/index.html' />
<link rel='canonical' href='index.html' />
<link rel='shortlink' href='index.html' />
        <style type="text/css">
            .comments-link {
                display: none;
            }
                    </style>...
```

Then, as you see, you search out a possible URL that could be it, so in this case it would be this URL that is link to a JavaScript file.

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://brigade3.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://brigade3.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js'></script>
```

Then just take `http://brigade3.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js` and shorten it down to `http://brigade3.com` and you found the site URL. I hope this is what you mean!

Comment: I don't think that could be automated reliably. A lot of pages will load JS libraries from a CDN, especially popular ones like jQuery.

Comment: Anyway, as I wrote in my answer, it isn't necessary as JSoup does store the URL the page was downloaded from in the Document object itself.

Comment: @VeselinRomic Majority of my site downloads usually leave a trace just like that. Theres always a way to find out the original URL just by looking through the code.

Comment: I realize that, I just mean it requires human judgement rather than something you could just write a script to do.